# How find files in a directory knowing a part of the name

Tags: java, file, directory, stream

I have a problem, i have this directory with 1k+ files and some folders. I need find the path of the files(which are in subdirectories) that starts with "BCM", but not only the first i find but every single file which start with that.

I tried looking at other answers about this topic but i couldn't find help,
tried using this code:

```
File dir = new File("K:\\Jgencs");
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() 
        {
         public boolean accept (File dir, String name) 
         { 
            return name.startsWith("BCM");
         }      
        }; 

        String[] children = dir.list(filter);
        if (children == null)
        {
            System.out.println("No directory found"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i< children.length; i++) 
            {
                String filename = children[i];
                    System.out.println(filename);
                    File h = new File(dir,filename);
                    System.out.println(h.getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Are those files in the directory itself or subdirectories? If they are in subdirectories you'll need to use a FileFilter to accept any directory or file that starts with BCM. If they are in the directory itself then a FilenameFilter is ok.

Comment: what do you mean by "the one in netbeans"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Don't use `File h = new File(filename);` because that will create a file reference in the current directory. Instead either use `File h = new File(dir, filename);` or `dir.listFiles(filter)` to get a `File[]` array instead of just an array of filenames.

Comment: Welcome @Shiro, I just posted an answer of how to achieve this using commons-io library.

Comment: @Shiro, Updated the answer with plain java and checking sub-directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED] This is how you can achieve using plain Java and filter text from a variable passing as parameter:

Here is my directory: /tmp

[image: Directory structure]

And here is the code running:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GetAllFilesInDirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filter = "BCM";

        List<File> files = listFiles("/tmp", new CustomerFileFilter(filter));
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
        }
    }

    private static List<File> listFiles(String directoryName, CustomerFileFilter fileFilter) {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

        // Get all files from a directory.
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles(fileFilter);
        if(fList != null) {
            for (File file : fList) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    files.add(file);
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    files.addAll(listFiles(file.getAbsolutePath(), fileFilter));
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
}

class CustomerFileFilter implements FileFilter {

    private final String filterStartingWith;

    public CustomerFileFilter(String filterStartingWith) {
        this.filterStartingWith = filterStartingWith;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory() || file.isFile() && file.getName().startsWith(filterStartingWith);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
file: /private/tmp/BCM01.txt
file: /private/tmp/BCM01
file: /private/tmp/subfolder1/BCM02.txt
```

Doing recursive calls to the method when finding a directory to also list the files form inside, and filtering by name the files before adding.

Comment: Note that BCM01 it is a file (not directory) it just doesn't contain extension.

Comment: Im trying your code, but i dont know how import that library in neatbeans

Comment: Hi @ShiroBestLoli , does your project is maven or gradle? Or is it a plain java?

Comment: is plain java, started programming 4 months ago so im still at "novice" level

Comment: Hi @ShiroBestLoli I updated the answer with a Plain Java example

Comment: This is going to subdirectories as well to retrieve the files.

Comment: There is a way to set the "bcm" with a variable from another class?

Answer (score -1):

You want [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...%29):

```
try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("K:\\Jgencs"))) {
    files.filter(f -> f.getFileName().toString().startsWith("BCM")).forEach(
        file -> System.out.println(file));
}
```

Comment: Tried use this, but it looks only at the files in the directory and not at every file(subdirectories)

Comment: Yes, just tested and this only looks in the current folder. And the question says to look in subdirectories.

Comment: @Brother So it does.  Updated.

Comment: I am running your code with my folder /tmp (the same from my example) and It doesn't print anything. And it is missing a  { in the try line

Comment: @Brother Missing brace added.  The code works perfectly for me.  Are you using `Paths.get("/tmp")`?